# Can I obtain true colours with .stl files from my 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, 3d-printing

I am trying to obtain 3D printable files from 3D plots with the code:

```
    modela = Plot3D[Sin[(x*y) + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]

    Printout3D[modela, "modela.stl"]
```

My final .stl file appeared monochromatic. I do not know if I can really obtain .stl files with all colour details from the 3D plot preserved. Thank you in anticipation of your expert opinions and suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the STL format does not include any sort of lighting or coloring. I think that such files are simply lists of vertices of triangles and their associated normal vectors, which is all you need to construct a shape.

The printer itself and its associated material is where the color will come from; I don't personally know anything about that process. However, a quick google suggests that the VRML filetype can support color, and this filetype is supported by Mathematica (use `.wrl` as the file extension). Hopefully this will do what you're looking for!

Also, a quick tip: you can use the `PlotPoints` option to really smooth this out before printing. `PlotPoints->120` seems to produce a very pleasant surface.